# Monitor file activities in a folder

Tags: linux, data-warehouse

We are a data warehousing team and we receive files from a variety of transfer mechanisms (SFTP, NDM etc) and would like to monitor the activities in our folders.  How can I get a list of all the files, the time it was arrived, the time it was removed from the folder etc.  Are there any utilities available for this?

Thanks!
Anand